# AngularJS - the purpose of hash in URL

Tags: angularjs, hash, routes, angular-ui-router

I am using `angular 1.5.8` and I have noticed that all of my states (routes) have a hash (`#` ) after the domain.

For example: 
`mydomain.com/#/profile`

After searching I found results explaining how to get rid of this hash, but I couldn't find an explanation to it's existence.

Why does that hash exist? Should I get rid of it? And if so why?

Thank you !

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes

Answer (score 1):

That is how angular makes routing possible without using HTML5 history API.

Have you ever seen parts of pages hyperlinked on a single page? (`href = "#<id-of-element">`) That's what angular exploits to make routing happen.

**Should you get rid of it?**
I say yes, because urls without # look cleaner. Make sure you do required changes for that. (html5mode and server redirection rules)